# Resource management in a mixed C# + WPF / C++ Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resources, resourcedictionary

I'm developing a Windows application using C# and WPF. This application has number crunching component and a rendering component written C++, and interop'd using C++/CLI, so that most of the application logic is in the C# part.

Now I'm wondering how to deal with resource management. Various components require resources, the WPF gui needs it's XAML icons and such, the renderer needs textures and the number crunching library needs some specific data too.

WPF offers a specific way of resource management using XAML and [ResourceDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.aspx). As all the C++ code is wrapped in C++/CLI, this would be accessible from within the wrapper, as far as I understand it.

I would like to have a unified resource management in my application, with all components using the same code for loading its data.

**What are the advantages and disadvantages when using the WPF ResourceDictionary for app-wide resource management?**

**What alternatives do I have to get unified resource handling (usable from WPF)**